# Cannotaccess MySQL from DBeaver

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

I'm new to this. I have a problem with DBeaver. I get a notification that there are drivers missing, but the list of drivers is empty. I have no Java installed on my laptop. Please help
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can download jar in your local,and set the class.[image]

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry, but I am new to this, could you please give more details?